# My microSD card doesn't work

Tags: sd-card

My microSD card doesn't work on my android, Alcatel One touch Pixi 3 4.5. It first came up with the error message "Damaged SD card". I have searched online and discovered the way of plugging it into your computer, opening command prompt and typing in "chkdsk f: /f". It "resolved" the problem, but then when I put it in my phone, it said "SD card safe to remove"?????

It did not work as I could not access any photos in the memory card and soon after trying to find out what is going on, the "Damaged SD card" notification popped up again!!!

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: Have you tried to reformat the card as FAT32 in a PC, then read and write data to it? Was this card working in your phone previously, or is this a new card?

Comment: It is a new card

Comment: @acejavelin I reformatted the card as FAT32 as you said, but when I put it back in my phone, it said"SD card safe to remove".

Comment: Has this card worked properly before in this phone, or is it "new"? Have you checked it with `SD Insight` from Play Store to be sure it isn't counterfeit?

Comment: @acejavelin It is brand new. I have checked it with other android phones and it does read the SD so I doubt it can be counterfeit...

Comment: Well, then if you absolutely sure the SD card is good and not counterfeit without verifying it, and another SD card exhibits the same behavior, your device is the problem. Factory default and retest. If it still fails, the device is defective.

Comment: The thing is, I had an old SD card in this phone before I lost it and it worked perfectly fine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37256/discussion-between-acejavelin-and-user0123456789).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to copy your photos and other data from your **SD card** to your PC(when the problem gets resolved by the **chkdsk** utility). Then format your **SD card** and copy the data back to it. Then try putting the car in you mobile phone. I think it would work for you. If not, then your SD card(according to my experience) is severely damaged and it is almost impossible to repair it.